# why are there multiple options for the same things in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a template design, and trying to change the various fonts.
I don't understand why  for example things seem repeated with the font sizes.

For example there is a set for H1 H2 H3

Then there is one just for h2 with some of the same specifications (such as text size, padding)

Also can someone explain why there are 4 options for padding? ie "9px, 0, 5px, 0"

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
  color: #FFF;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

h1, h2, h3 { 
  font: normal 140% 'News Cycle', arial;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
}

h2 { 
  font-size: 160%;
  padding: 9px 0 5px 0;
}
h
h3 { 
  font-size: 140%;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}

h4, h6 { 
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  font: normal 120% 'Droid Sans', arial, sans-serif;
}

h5, h6 { 
  font: italic 100% 'Droid Sans', arial;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
}

h6 { 
   font: normal 100% 'Droid Sans', arial;
}
```

Comment: Use some css code beautifier and it will automatically save you the trouble. [Here's one](http://www.codebeautifier.com/) that might help. As for why the template is like that, you would have to ask the maker :) --- Padding has 4 values, that's the short way to add top,right,bottom,left padding in that order.

Comment: @pol  lol I'm trying to figure out why they did that, like if there was some good reason, or just a stupid thing they did, because it makes it hard for me to change since I'm not sure if I will be changing more than one thing at once.    Thanks for the css code beautifier! Now I have a new toy!   Seems like a funny order for padding, but it makes sense now.  anyway thanks again!

Comment: It sounds to me like you're not asking about problems you're encountering, but about design decisions made by someone else. "Why did they do this" rather than "How". I'm afraid this isn't the place for those kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1):

The padding property can be defined using up to 4 parameters.
If four parameters are defined, then:

- The first parameter specifies `padding-top`
- The second parameter specifies `padding-right`
- The third parameter specifies `padding-bottom`
- The fourth parameter specifies `padding-left`

If three parameters are defined, then:

- The first parameter specifies `padding-top`
- The second parameter specifies both `padding-right` and `padding-left`
- The third parameter specifies `padding-bottom`

If two parameters are defined, then:

- The first parameter specifies both `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`
- The second parameter specifies both `padding-right` and `padding-left`

If one parameter is defined, then it specifies all 4 properties.

If no parameter is defined, then all four properties will be set to their default values, which is zero.

Regarding the `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>` and `<h6>` tags, the user first specified general properties for all tags, then began to specify the unique properties of some of the tags. For example, the user has set the font, margin and padding properties for all `<h1>`, `<h2>` and `<h3>` tags, but then set the font-size property for each tag alone.